# Git: Problems with branches on OS X

Tags: git, bash, version-control

Hi everyone I'm currently facing a stressful problem on git.When I try to modify a specific branch,git saves the changes in the other branches too.These are my terminal records:

```
Pro-di-Mirko:gitfun mirko$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
new file:   .DS_Store
modified:   gitfun.swift
Pro-di-Mirko:gitfun mirko$ git branch
addingFunction
master
Pro-di-Mirko:gitfun mirko$ git checkout addingFunction
A .DS_Store
M gitfun.swift
Switched to branch 'addingFunction'
Pro-di-Mirko:gitfun mirko$ git status
On branch addingFunction
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
new file: .DS_Store
modified: gitfun.swift
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   gitfun.swift
Pro-di-Mirko:gitfun mirko$ git add -A
Pro-di-Mirko:gitfun mirko$ gi status
-bash: gi: command not found
Pro-di-Mirko:gitfun mirko$ git status
On branch addingFunction
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
new file:   .DS_Store
modified:   gitfun.swift
Pro-di-Mirko:gitfun mirko$ git branch
addingFunction
master
Pro-di-Mirko:gitfun mirko$ git checkout master
A .DS_Store
M gitfun.swift
Switched to branch 'master'
Pro-di-Mirko:gitfun mirko$ git branch
addingFunction
master
Pro-di-Mirko:gitfun mirkodevita$
```

In my swift file if I checkout different branches nothing happens, the file remains identical

Comment: It seems like you have a misunderstanding of what `git add` does. This stages files to be commited to the branch you're currently on. So you need to add a `git commit` to actually make it part of the branch.

Answer (score 1):

You never committed your changes.

`git add` says "add this to my *next commit*". It puts it in a thing called the "staging area". Once you've added all your changes to the staging area, `git commit` turns them into a commit.

There is only one staging area. If you check out a different branch you'll still be using the same staging area. Since you only ran `git add` and not `git commit` switching between branches shows you the same staged changes.

[Here's a good illustration of the staging area](http://www.git-scm.com/about/staging-area). And this [describes the basic workflow and has a nice illustration of how data move around in Git](http://blog.osteele.com/posts/2008/05/my-git-workflow/).